# Wireless issues Freya vs (Ubuntu & Windows)

Tags: wifi, networking, drivers

I have a 5Ghz wifi network with an SSID of *'spark1_5'*, but my desktop with ElementaryOS Freya (Kernel 3.19) does not see it. *spark1_5* is on channel 132 of the 5Ghz spectrum. Upon running *iwlist wlan0 freq*, it does not list channel 132 as a supported channel.

I then downloaded and booted up a live Ubuntu 15.10 image and I can see my 5Ghz SSID *spark1_5* and connect to it. Running the *iwlist wlan0 freq* command now lists channel 132 as a supported channel. I also booted up a copy of Windows 10 to see if it was my card or my Access Point. Windows 10 saw the *spark1_5* SSID and connected to it easily as well.

So is there an outdated version of ath9k in Freya? Why would Ubuntu 15.10 and Windows 10 allow my card to see channel 132 where Freya does not?

I'm a total noob at linux, so any input would be appreciated! Thanks!